# Creating a variable with observation number based on date and id number for participants with multiple observations

Tags: datetime, time-series, spss, mixed-models

I have a database with 100 participants, identified by the variable 'id'.The database also includes a 'StartDate' variable indicating the date and time each participant took the survey in the format 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss'. One observation per day.

I want to create a new variable called 'observation' that indicates the number of observations for each participant according to the date variable. If there is a 2-day gap, the number skips 2.

For example, if a participant has observations on 11.10.2023 23:08:13, 12.10.2023 22:01:12, 13.10.2023 20:14:17, 14.10.2023 10:30:18, 14.10.2023 19:45:18 the 'observation' variable should take the values 1, 3, 3, 4, and 5 respectively.

If a participant skipped a day, the 'observation' number should jump. For example, if a participant has observations on 11.10.2023 23:08:13, 13.10.2023 20:14:17, 14.10.2023 19:30:18, 16.10.2023 19:45:18, the 'observation' variable should take the values 1, 3, 4, and 6 respectively.

How can I write an SPSS syntax?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want - two interviews in the same date, the number is still +1, but skip a day and the number skips? what if there is a 2 day gap, also the number skips 2? what would the number look like when there were two observation in the same day, and then a day was skipped - is it 1,2,3 or 1,2,4? Please edit your post to make the numbering method more clear so we can help you get what you need.

Comment: @eli-k You are right. I tried to put two different things in one to simplify the question but it turns more confusing. I edited the question to improve clarification.

Comment: This is clearer, but since questions in SO are required to focus on one specific problem I would ask you to separate the post into two, each dealing with a different problem. While you're at it, I will answer the first question - see maybe it will help you with the second one too anyway.

Comment: @eli-k Thank you, Your answer helped me with the first part. I'll split this question into a second question as I find the second part even more complicated because it should take into consideration the hours as well, and I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate the `observation` variable you need to change the date-time variable into a date only.
If it is originally in text format, do this:

```
COMPUTE YourDate=number(YourOldDate, DATE8).
FORMATS YourDate (DATE9).
```

If it is originally in number or date-time format, do this:

```
compute YourDate=YourOldDate.
alter type YourDate (DATE8).
FORMATS YourDate (DATE9).
```

Now we can calculate the `observation`, by comparing the date in each line to the previous one. The `max` function is added so in cases of zero difference in days since previous observation we still add 1.

```
sort cases by ID YourDate.
compute observation=1.
if $casenum>1 and ID=lag(ID) 
    observation=lag(observation)+max(datediff(YourDate,lag(YourDate),"days"),1).
exe.
```